# Formal definition of a 'genetic trait reservoir'?

Tags: nomenclature

I've read the [tomato genome paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature11119) in Nature published recently, and they describe the tomato genetic resource as a rich `trait reservoir` that *will provide biological knowledge and empower biodiversity-based breeding*. What would be a formal definition of `trait reservoir` in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, "trait reservoir" refers to the set of all possible alleles for all the different genes in the organism. The more different alleles the organism has, the more possible genotypes it might have. The Nature paper might have referred specifically to the set of *known* allelic variants.